# hplip-gui and Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, hplip

My first post here, I've asked elsewhere but no joy..

I wonder if anyone can help me with an issue I am having with my HP Envy 5020 printer. The printer can be connected either wirelessly or via USB and it gets installed automatically by Ubuntu.

The problem is when I install the hplip-gui package and run the HPLIP Toolbox. This allows me to then see more detail about the printer such as ink levels.

When I run the setup it asks what type of connection do I want to use

1. USB
2. Network/Ethernet/Wireless network (direct connection or JetDirect)
3. Wireless/802.11(requires a temporary USB connection and is only available for select devices)

Previously I have selected option 3, clicked next at which point it lists my printer and then I click next, it then asks for wi-fi details etc and then completes, tells me to remove the USB cable and go to hp-setup 192.168.0.13 to finalise installation after which I can see the ink levels and scan directly from the HPLIP Toolbox.

Since installing a fresh copy of 20.04 when I run the setup up I get the choose connection option, plug in the USB lead and click next, it lists my printer on the next screen but when I highlight it and click next I get a communication error, an I/O error occurred Please check the USB connection to your printer and try again. (Device I/O error)

I can confirm the USB cable is OK, which would make sense as it detects the printer over USB, but to be sure I have tried the cable in a different PC and printer. I have also tried another cable.

I have also tried running a live USB of 20.04 as my actual install is the minimal version so I wondered if that was the issue, same thing. I have tried a live USB with Kubuntu 20.04 and the same thing. I then tried with a live USB of 18.04 and the printer installed perfectly!

Can anyone shed any light on this please, whether it's the hplip-gui package causing the problem or some other packages that haven't been included in the 20.04 ISO?

Comment: Do you have a wi-fi network with a router, and is your printer connected to the network? If so, have you tried option #2?

Comment: Can you `tail -f` the system log and then repeat the process?

When this error comes up, there should be something meaningful in the logs. Please update your post with those logs.  By [pega041](https://askubuntu.com/users/986521/pega041)